# ZipEntry setSize not working + How does 7Zip do it? (JAVA)

Tags: java, zip, 7zip

I was wondering.

I have this code to zip multiple files:

```
try (ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputZip))) {
    for (Entry<File, String> entry : fileMap.entrySet()) {

        // name the file inside the zip file
        ZipEntry zEntry = new ZipEntry(entry.getValue());
        logger.info("UNCOMPRESSED FILE SIZE:" + entry.getKey().length());
        zEntry.setSize(entry.getKey().length());
        out.putNextEntry(zEntry);

        int length;
        try (BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(entry.getKey()))) {

            while ((length = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

        }
        out.flush();

    }

    out.flush();
}
```

This works fine to create my zip files (the files to be zipped are supplied in a Map) - however, zEntry.setSize does not work. The logger output looks like this:

```
09:40:47,909 INFO (Thread-302) UNCOMPRESSED FILE SIZE:59663
09:40:47,912 INFO (Thread-302) UNCOMPRESSED FILE SIZE:59663
09:40:47,915 INFO (Thread-302) UNCOMPRESSED FILE SIZE:652119
09:40:47,930 INFO (Thread-302) UNCOMPRESSED FILE SIZE:1291206
```

But upon unzipping, zEntry.getSize() yields -1. 
( `09:39:57,240 INFO (default task-90) -1` )

Now, I've read that this is a bug in Java, but I've also read that it's supposedly fixed. I wonder how 7zip does it for Instance, as it can display filesizes (uncompressed) within it's GUI as well, even with the same archives I'm using here. Is it a language quirk or does 7zip actually unpack the files when you open them with the filemanager (even if it's just into memory?) to display the size?

Comment: You are missing an `out.closeEntry()` at the end of each entry (you are not the first)

Comment: Does it come before or after the flush?

Comment: At the end of writing an entry, before `}` of the for loop. It for instance checks that the size fo the entry matches the written bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now. My unzip code was using a ZipfileInputStream, which seems to have some issues. I used ZipFile, ZipFile.getEntry, and ZipFile.getInputStream(entry) instead - this worked fine, the ZipEntry returned by getEntry has the Size set correctly and I am no longer wasting space (if too small) or running into exceptions (if too large) by allocating a fixed size 32kb read buffer every time.